# VC++ Winforms passing member function as argument to BackgroundWorker

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-c++, backgroundworker

Being a beginner, I am struggling with the syntax here.
I am making a generic BackgroundWorker to avoid making separate workers for each of the many tasks in my application.
I am unable to figure out how to *pass a member function to RunWorkerAsync()*

**Here is my DoWork method's code:**

```
private: System::Void backgroundWorker2_DoWork(System::Object^  sender, System::ComponentModel::DoWorkEventArgs^  e) {
    Func<int> ^func = (Func<int>^)e->Argument;
    e->Result = func();
}
```

Let's say I want the BG worker to run a function named myfunc.
I want to do something like this: RunWorkerAsync(myfunc)

While myfunc is a member of the same class i.e Form1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't clear to me what the hangup might be, the syntax to create the Func<> isn't very different from the way you subscribe the DoWork event.  So just some sample code:

```
ref class Example {
    BackgroundWorker^ worker;
    void OnDoWork(System::Object ^sender, System::ComponentModel::DoWorkEventArgs ^e) {
        auto job = safe_cast<Func<int>^>(e->Argument);
        e->Result = job();
    }
    int myfunc() {
        return 42;
    }
public:
    Example() : worker(gcnew BackgroundWorker) {
        worker->DoWork += gcnew System::ComponentModel::DoWorkEventHandler(this, &Example::OnDoWork);
        auto job = gcnew Func<int>(this, &Example::myfunc);
        worker->RunWorkerAsync(job);
    }
};
```

Comment: But also is there a way to generalize the type of the function? I mean, what if I want to call a function that returns String^ instead of int?

Comment: Then you use a `Func<String^>^` instead.